# Kali Linux(WSL) not recognizing wireless adapter

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, airmon-ng, aircrack-ng

I have installed Kali Linux on my Windows 10 laptop through the Microsoft store. Now when I use the command `iwconfig`, it says no wireless extensions next wifi0, wifi1 and wifi2. So I thought my built-in wireless adapter is not capable of monitor mode, however, I have Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 installed in my Laptop and it successfully captures packets, so to my understanding, my built-in adapter is capable of monitor mode.

My question is essentially why does it say "no wireless extensions" because I won't be able to use `airmon-ng` unless this is resolved. I'm relatively new to Kali Linux so please forgive if my understanding of the situation is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is not (yet) implemented in WSL.

To add one [quote](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1104#issuecomment-248708210):

> **fpqc** commented on 21 Sep 2016
>
> The way it works right now, the Win32-side networking settings control the kernel, which then controls the LX-side networking. There are no real networking devices set up in /dev on the LX side, at the moment at least.

There are many duplicates of the same type in the WSL issue tracker on github:

- [WSL Not Detecting wireless adapters #5041](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5041)
- [Problems with WiFi interface when type airmon-ng in Kali linux #5005](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5005)
- [iwconfig - no wireless extensions #3270](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3270)

etc...